# UIActivityViewController: how to enable "Save to Files" action in Share Sheet

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am using UIActivityViewController to share a file with an own extension (declared under Document Types and Exported UTIs). The file is actually a .zip file using a different extension.

The Share Sheet appears and works as expected, but the "Save to Files" is not available.

When using exact the same code to export a ".pkpass" (Wallet) file, the Share Sheet includes the "Save to Files" option, so the reason must be related to the file type.

I tried adding "public.zip-archive" (and others) to the conforms to fields of the Document Type and Exported UTI but this did not resolve the issue.

What steps need to be performed to add the "Save to Files" actions to the Share Sheet in such a case?

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I'm having the same issue too

Comment: Unfortunately not, @fphelp .